# julia language bitwise or in if statement

Tags: julia

I am using Julia 0.3.0 on Windows 8.1

I enter the following:

```
julia> Y, M = 2000, 2
(2000,2)

julia> if M == 1 | M == 2
           Y -= 1
           M += 12
       end

julia> Y, M
(2000,2)
```

I expected Y = 1999, M = 14

Apparently this is not the way to use the bitwise or  ( | )
How do I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `||` (http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/control-flow/#man-short-circuit-evaluation) for control flow `or`.

The issue in this case is the operator precedence: `|` is bitwise-or which is higher than equality, see http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/mathematical-operations/. It works if you do `(M==1)|(M==2)`, for example. Its unclear if the precedence should change, [people are talking about the issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/5187) at least.